# Tk inter how to make event Menu wait for custom Popup

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an issue with using Menu which opens another window. The issue is that when I open a Tk Menu, rest of the code waits until the Menu is closed, however when I click on an item from Menu, the rest of the code runs, even thought the clicked item is not finished. The code representing the problem is:

main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import main_Functions as Functions

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Treeview demo')
root.geometry('620x200')
columns = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings')
tree.heading('first_name', text='First Name')
tree.heading('last_name', text='Last Name')
tree.heading('email', text='Email')
contacts = []
for n in range(1, 5):
    contacts.append((f'first {n}', f'last {n}', f'email{n}@example.com'))
for contact in contacts:
    tree.insert('', tk.END, values=contact)

tree.bind("<Button-3>", Functions.click)

tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

root.mainloop()
```

main_Functions.py:

```
def click(e):
    my_popup_input(e)
    if output_variable == "Inp":
        print("You wrote Inp")
    else:
        print("You did not write Inp")

def my_popup_input(e):
    
    my_menu = Menu(e.widget, tearoff=0)
    my_menu.add_command(label="Menu_1", command= lambda: input_box(e))
    my_menu.add_command(label="Menu_2", command= lambda: input_box(e))
    my_menu.tk_popup(e.x_root, e.y_root)
    
    
def input_box(e):
    global input_box_screen
    
    def btn_press():
        global output_variable
        output_variable = entry.get()
        input_box_screen.destroy()
    input_box_screen = Tk()       
    
    entry = Entry(input_box_screen)
    entry.pack()   
    btn = Button (input_box_screen, text = "Confirm")
    btn.pack()
    btn.configure(command = btn_press)
```

The problem is, that when I right click on the Treeview and press on an Item from menu, error is raised at line `if output_variable == "Inp":` that `output_variable` is not declared - which means the code does not wait for `my_popup_input(e)` to be finished. The issue could be solved with `.wait_window`, if I would not use Menu with even `e`. But in this case I am not able to use this as I do not want a window to wait, but an event.

My assumtion is that there must be some kind of wait function put in `def my_popup_input(e):` but unfurtunatelly I do not know which.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified the main_Functions.py file:

1. Replaced input_box_screen = Tk() with Toplevel() so there should be one root window per application. [Windows and Dialogs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html)
2. I tied it to the Entry widget string_var, for more dynamic tracking of what the user is typing there.
3. In order to get rid of global variables I used "partial" to pass variables to callback functions.

I think it turned out close to what you wanted.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial


def click(e):
    my_popup_input(e)


def my_popup_input(e):
    my_menu = Menu(e.widget, tearoff=0)
    my_menu.add_command(label="Menu_1", command=lambda: input_box(e))
    my_menu.add_command(label="Menu_2", command=lambda: input_box(e))
    my_menu.tk_popup(e.x_root, e.y_root)


def btn_press(var, box):
    print(f"You wrote:    {var.get()}")
    box.destroy()


def input_box(e):
    input_box_screen = Toplevel()

    string_var = StringVar()
    entry = Entry(input_box_screen, textvariable=string_var)
    entry.pack()
    entry.focus()

    btn = Button(input_box_screen, text="Confirm", command=partial(btn_press, string_var, input_box_screen))
    btn.pack()
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem exactly, because the menu still does not wait for `input_box` function to be finished. You have essentially moved the print function into the menu function. 

However what is my purpose is to have the output variable, which comes from the right click on the treeview and clicking a Menu button to be useable **after** the menu is closed. that is the reason why in my initial function I first put `my_popup_input(e)`, followed by printing of the output variable if `output_variable == "Inp": `